# OSX Lion 10.7.3 update has broken Safari

Tags: macos, safari, bug

This happened right after I have upgraded to 10.7.3 via Software Update utility. Or maybe even 10.7.2 unfortunately cannot recall now.

Before update I saw nice page saying that Safari cannot connect to remote host.

Now I'm getting meaningless garbage. See [sample screenshot](http://skit.ch/ncap). (My reputation is not high enough to post images)

Does anybody knows how this can be fixed?

Just to be clear, nothing is listening on localhost:8000

Comment: Seems like font caches problem. There are several programs that clean the font caches (you can find them easily) but I can't recommend any of them as I haven't used any of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update to Safari 6.0 has fixed the problem.